# Best transformation for consumer goods?

Tags: regression, model

I am using Data Analysis regression in Excel to model the demand for consumer goods at various price points. I need to use transformations to more accurately model consumer demand.

The Power Model (log of dependent and log of independent variables) achieves the highest R^2 but seems to show volume predictions jumping up really fast as price decreases. I don't know if I trust that. Log model has just slightly less R^2 but doesn't get so wild in the extreme low/high price areas of the graph.

```
VOL     PRICE
3044    4.97
2549    4.97
3131    4.98
2708    4.98
2860    4.98
2907    4.98
3107    4.98
3194    4.98
2753    4.98
3228    4.98
3019    4.98
3077    4.99
2597    4.99
2706    4.99
3000    4.99
3022    4.99
3084    4.99
3973    4.99
3675    4.99
3065    4.99
3407    4.99
2359    4.99
2802    4.99
2589    4.99
2476    4.99
2387    5
3265    5
2039    5.14
1842    5.15
2660    5.37
1796    5.46
1734    5.46
1881    5.46
2204    5.58
1477    5.77
1620    5.84
1909    5.87
1744    5.87
1247    5.87
1848    5.88
1641    5.88
1758    5.88
1718    5.88
1656    5.88
1822    5.88
1556    5.89
1643    5.9
1850    5.91
1901    5.91
1837    5.91
1773    5.92
1729    5.92
```

Does anyone have any insight as to which transformation model best describes consumer goods? Grocery to be exact.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you edit your question and include your data, or at least a scatterplot $y \sim x$ and histograms for the variables. Also, power transform is usually chosen by means of BoxCox procedure.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Do you have any advice?

Comment: This exercise will not yield anything economically meaningful unless you make some restrictive assumptions about how prices are determined.

Comment: Please explain Dimitriy - These are actual amounts sold at various price points for the last 52 weeks. How is that not meaningful? I can choose price going forward. I want to predict how much I will sell at various price points.

Comment: @JohnsonJason Did you (or someone at the firm) pick these prices at random or are they determined by market forces?

Comment: They are not determined by market forces. We set the price. These are the volumes at various price points. The whole point is I want to understand market forces "the demand" so I can optimize the price.

Comment: But were they picked *at random*, without regard to demand shocks? This is the crucial detail.

Comment: When you say "jumps up really fast" ... you don't happen to be projecting outside the range of the data (i.e. below PRICE=4.97) do you?

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, Yes I mapped out a graph outside of the data range (both high and low). Shouldn't I be able to project outside the range of data (at least a little distance) with some accuracy? That's what makes regression so useful for me. Ability to understand the effect of prices never tried.

Comment: Hi @DimitriyV.Masterov , can you explain what you are getting at? As far as I know price is a good predictor of volume sold. If you believe it isn't for some reason please explain.

Comment: I am worried that the high prices correspond to periods of increased demand. For example, the managers may know that there's an event in town (high positive error term) and adjust prices. If that is the case, your price sensitivity will be biased toward zero because of the endogeneity bias. There is a subtle difference between saying I know what the volume will be when the price happens to be 5 versus I know what the volume will be when I set the price at 5. My dog is happy when he wags his tail, but he may cease to be that way when I wag his tail for him.

Comment: Thank you Dimitriy, I appreciate the explanation. It's always important to untangle the complicated relationship between cause and effect. In this case I think the math can show that PRICE is driving the number of units sold, Barring a holiday week such as thanksgiving of course. So with that aside I still don't have an answer to the original question. Any insight in that regard? Thanks again.